# primeng p-treeTableToggler icon changed instead of original pi pi-fw pi-chevron-right icon

Tags: javascript, angular, primeng, primeicons

I'm using `primeng tree toggler` for a grid in angular application.

For `tree toggler` icon, `primeicons`  are used.

https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/icons

Using below CSS for `toggler` icon.

```
.pi-chevron-right:before {
    content: '\e905' !important;
    vertical-align: middle !important;
    font-size: 25px;
}
```

But image is getting differently compared to original icons.

**Expected toggler icon:**

[image]

**Existing toggler icon:**

[image]

I want to get icon as shown in Expected toggler icon but getting the wrong icon, Existing toggler icon.

How to avoid that.

**Update 1:**

I'm able to get toggler icon as expected, if I remove below highlighted styles .

[image]
[image]

I tried in chrome developer tools.It worked.

But I'm not getting how to remove them from angular/javascript code. Kindly suggest.

Comment: Isn'it the '\e901' you should use as content of before?

Comment: No. I should use same styles given in query.Actually It was working earlier, but from the last few days, icon got changed but same css exists. I'm not getting why icon got changed inspite of having same old css which was working earlier.

Comment: Why don't use the class instead of doing the css? I can't find the "existing toggler icon" on the page of link you shared.

Comment: actually I have used primeng treetoggler https://primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/treetable and css used for chevron is default one.I just imported primeng library and used it in my app.